# MySQL division precision

Tags: mysql

```
mysql> SELECT 100 / 35600.00 * 35600.00;

+---------------------------+
| 100 / 35600.00 * 35600.00 |
+---------------------------+
|                 99.999973 |
+---------------------------+

mysql> SELECT TRUNCATE(100 / 35600.00, 30) * 35600.00;

+-----------------------------------------+
| TRUNCATE(100 / 35600.00, 30) * 35600.00 |
+-----------------------------------------+
|       99.999972800000000000000000000000 |
+-----------------------------------------+
```

Comment: mysql> SELECT TRUNCATE(100/35600.00, 30)*35600.00;
+-------------------------------------+
| TRUNCATE(100/35600.00, 30)*35600.00 |

+-------------------------------------+

|   99.999972800000000000000000000000 |

+-------------------------------------+

Comment: It's really not clear what you're asking or what the problem is. Are you wondering why the arithmetic seems to be off by a small amount? Please edit your question so we can give you a proper answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should use `TRUNCATE()` in MySQL for your purpose:

```
SELECT TRUNCATE(100 / 35600.00 * 35600.00, 2);
```

It will provide you result as `99.99`

There's a problem with using `TRUNCATE()` - it will not round off. So I suggest you to use `ROUND()` function instead:

```
SELECT ROUND(100 / 35600.00 * 35600.00, 2);
```

Result: `100.00`

Comment: I don't know if this is the correct answer because I don't know what the question is, but given the prompt, this is a good attempt.